# Unity is crashing when I open a scene. No Warning or explanation

Tags: ios, macos, unity-game-engine, logging, crash

I am using Unity 2020.3.28 LTS and I have a project that I have been working on on both my laptop (mac) and desktop (pc). When I pushed an update to git then moved to my laptop to work on it from there the project no longer worked. It would open but to an untitled scene but as soon as I opened my game scene (the only scene in the project) unity closes. In the log files I found this in the AssetImportWorker0.log file

AssetImportWorkerClient::OnTransportError - code=2 error=End of file

The project and everything still works flawlessly on my pc. I also tried updating the unity version and reinstalling the unity hub and unity and I have deleted and reinstalled my project

Answer (score 0):

What are your Git commit settings? If it works fine in Windows and crashes on a Mac, especially after pushing to Git, I would wonder if your new line settings are screwed up.

Is your Mac trying to check out with Windows newline characters?

https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_for_windows_line_endings.html

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings